# Run async code before entire mocha test

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, mocha.js

I'm looking for a way to run async code before the entire mocha test.

Here's an example of a test that uses an array of arguments & expectations and loops over all of the items in this array to produce function assertions.

```
var assert = require('assert')

/* global describe, it*/

var fn = function (value) {
  return value + ' ' + 'pancake'
}

var tests = [
  {
    'arg': 'kitty',
    'expect': 'kitty pancake'
  },
  {
    'arg': 'doggy',
    'expect': 'doggy pancake'
  },
]

describe('example', function () {
  tests.forEach(function (test) {
    it('should return ' + test.expect, function (){
      var value = fn(test.arg)
      assert.equal(value, test.expect)
    })
  })
})
```

Now, my question is how would this work if the tests value came from a promise, like this:

```
var assert = require('assert')
var Promise = require('bluebird')

/* global describe, it*/

var fn = function (value) {
  return value + ' ' + 'pancake'
}

function getTests () {
  return Promise.resolve('kitty pancake')
  .delay(500)
  .then(function (value) {
    return [
      {
        'arg': 'kitty',
        'expect': value
      },
      {
        'arg': 'doggy',
        'expect': 'doggy pancake'
      }
    ]
  })
}

getTests().then(function (tests) {
  describe('example', function () {
    tests.forEach(function (test) {
      it('should return ' + test.expect, function (){
        var value = fn(test.arg)
        assert.equal(value, test.expect)
      })
    })
  })  
})
```

also tried:

```
describe('example', function () {
  getTests().then(function (tests) {
    tests.forEach(function (test) {
      it('should return ' + test.expect, function (){
        var value = fn(test.arg)
        assert.equal(value, test.expect)
      })
    })
  })
})
```

However in this example none of the tests run because mocha doesn't recognize the describe statement because it's within a promise.

`before` / `beforeEach` won't do anything to help with a test in the format anyway unless the was a `beforeTest` hook that would supply mocha with the knowledge that there's an async operation that needs to be run before the entire test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is any easy way to do this, but you could try to [run Mocha programatically](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically).

Here is a little dirty version of what this could look like, just to show the idea.

`data.js`

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')

module.exports.tests = []

function getTests () {
  return Promise.resolve('kitty pancake')
  .delay(500)
  .then(function (value) {
     module.exports.tests = [
      {
        'arg': 'kitty',
        'expect': value
      },
      {
        'arg': 'doggy',
        'expect': 'doggy pancake'
      }
    ]
  })
}

module.exports.getTests = getTests
```

`test-launcher.js`

```
var Mocha = require('mocha'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path')

// First, you need to instantiate a Mocha instance.
var mocha = new Mocha()

// Then, you need to use the method "addFile" on the mocha
// object for each file.

// Here is an example:
fs.readdirSync('test').filter(function(file){
    // Only keep the .js files
    return file.substr(-3) === '.js'

}).forEach(function(file){
    // Use the method "addFile" to add the file to mocha
    mocha.addFile(
        path.join('test', file)
    )
})

// make sure your tests are loaded before running the tests
require('./data').getTests().then(function () {

  // Now, you can run the tests.
  mocha.run(function(failures){
    process.on('exit', function () {
      process.exit(failures)
    })
  })
})
```

`test/index.js`

```
var assert = require('assert')

var tests = require('../data').tests

var fn = function (value) {
  return value + ' ' + 'pancake'
}

describe('test', function () {
  describe('example', function () {
    tests.forEach(function (test) {
      it('should return ' + test.expect, function (){
        var value = fn(test.arg)
        assert.equal(value, test.expect)
      })
    })
  })
})
```

You can then run you rests by running `test-launcher.js`.

Comment: How would this live in the `test` folder? I need it to play nicely with other test when I run `mocha` and code coverage?

Comment: Only tests should live in the `test` folder, `test-launcher.js` should be either at the root of your project, or in a directory containing other utilities if you have one. Code coverage should work perfectly well, for example, with istanbul, `istanbul cover test-launcher.js` should give you what you want.
I created a sample project with code coverage, give it a look.
https://github.com/tuvistavie/mocha-async-test

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to Daniel Perez's method you can also [use the command line switch `--delay` and start the tests on the first `run()` call](https://mochajs.org/#delayed-root-suite). By delaying the `run()` asynchronously you can register `describe`s and `it`s asynchronously beforehand. Note, though, that you can only call `run()` once, i.e. only in one test file. Thus I've created an async test runner in `./test/` and each async test in `./testAsync/`:

```
// ./test/asyncRunner.js
"use strict";

const allAsyncPaths = [
  "test-featureA",
  "test-featureB",
].map(a => "../testAsync/" + a);

const allAsyncTestFunctions = allAsyncPaths.map(require);

Promise.resolve({
}).then(function() {
  const allPromises = allAsyncTestFunctions.map(a => a());
  return Promise.all(allPromises);
}).then(function() {
  run(); // mocha waits for run() because of --delay flag
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

and

```
// ./testAsync/test-featureA.js
"use strict";
function asyncTestRegistrator() {

  return Promise.resolve({
  }).then(function() {
    return getTestsAsync();
  }).then(function(tests) {

  describe('example', function () {
    tests.forEach(function (test) {
      it('should return ' + test.expect, function (){
        var value = fn(test.arg);
        assert.equal(value, test.expect);
      });
    });
  });
}
module.exports = asyncTestRegistrator;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the async/await with [delay option](https://mochajs.org/#delayed-root-suite) as below:

```
setTimeout(async () => {
//get tests async
const tests = await getTests()

describe('example', async () => {

  tests.forEach((test) => {
   it(`test name: ${test.name} `, () => {
    console.log(test.name)
  })
 })
})

run()
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply the delay but run the tests as soon as the data is fetched?

Comment: **Update**: that is precisely what `run` does.

Answer (score -2):

I would move the async logic within the `it` call. Getting too fancy with unit tests is a code smell and likely to just irritate other developers when they not only have to debug and fix failing tests but have to debug and fix tests that aren't even defined and running because the fancy setup code has bugs. Try hard not to go there.

```
var assert = require('assert')
var Promise = require('bluebird')

/* global describe, it*/

var fn = function(value) {
  return value + ' ' + 'pancake'
}

function getTests() {
  return Promise.resolve('kitty pancake')
    .delay(500)
    .then(function(value) {
      return [
        {
          'arg': 'kitty',
          'expect': value
        },
        {
          'arg': 'doggy',
          'expect': 'doggy pancake'
        }
      ]
    })
}

describe('example', function() {
  it('should handle many things', function(done) {
    getTests().then(function(tests) {
      tests.forEach(function(test) {
        var value = fn(test.arg)
        assert.equal(value, test.expect, 'should return ' + test.expect)
      })
      done()
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: I love this solution, it seems simple, however the lack of issuing `it` statements doesn't provide me with any information if the assertion I'm running is successful.